When is the diagonal morphism regular?
Let $X$ denote a smooth algebraic variety over a field $k$. When is the diagonal map $X \to X \times_{k} X$ regular?
This question is somewhat related to Diagonal morphism of regular variety is a regular embedding I guess.

I don't quite understand your question. The diagonal morphism is a closed immersion, hence an isomorphism into its image which is closed. Usually, regular implies flat, so that the image cannot be a strict closed subset. I believe you mean something else?

I guess the OP means regular in the following sense https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_embedding.
